# vuejs v-model on multiple checkboxes

Tags: vue.js, checkbox

I'm having a hard time figuring out why all my checkboxes are becoming checked at once in my mapped vuejs  tags.

I only want to check them one at a time but I can't remove the checkbox inputs from inside the

or my reference to student.someValue becomes undefined.

```
<div class="modal-body modalBody" >
  <form @submit.prevent="makeExclusionGroup">
   <ul>
     <li class="listItems" v-for="(student, index) in students">
      {{student.first_name}}
      <input v-model="toExclude.selected" id="student.index" :value="student.full_name" type="checkbox"> 
     </li>                  
   </ul>
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have set a single model value `toExclude.selected` to all of the checkboxes, which means all of the checkbox now will have the same effect. So, to resolve this issue you can simply add a property like `selected` to `student` object so that each single checkbox will have its own value.

**Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
  data: {
    students: [{text: 'Student 1', selected:false},{text: 'Student 2', selected:false},{text: 'Student 3', selected:false}]
  },
  methods: {
  }
})
```

```css
ul li { display: inline-block; padding: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="myApp">
  <ul>
     <li class="listItems" v-for="(student, index) in students">
      {{student.text}}
      <input v-model="student.selected" id="index" :value="student.text" type="checkbox"> 
     </li>                  
   </ul>
   <br/>
   <h5>Selected Options:</h5>
   <pre>{{students.map(s=>s.selected)}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, suspected something had to be all 1 value, didn't realize what ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `v-model` for each check box.

All your checkboxes are referencing the same `model`.

Try to change it to use a flag on the `student`

```
<li class="listItems" v-for="(student, index) in students">
  {{student.first_name}}
  <input v-model="student.isSelected" id="student.index" :value="student.full_name" type="checkbox"> 
</li>
```

And then you can filter based on `isSelected` to get the selected students

```
students.filter(student => student.isSelected)
```